# osisoft piconfig export csv into regular pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, osisoft

I have some issues trying to import csv files from osisoft piconfig export into regular pandas DF.

I am a beginner in Python, so if you are kind enough to answer me, I kindly ask you to explain in details if possible.

The raw data looks like this:

```
"*> sensor_1"," 09-aug-22 10:36"," 09-aug-22 10:36"," 100000000000"
"sensor_1","9-Aug-22 10:36:00.0000 CUT","-31.10765",""
"sensor_1","9-Aug-22 10:36:01.0000 CUT","-30.58978",""
"sensor_1","9-Aug-22 10:36:02.0000 CUT","-30.14589",""
"sensor_1","9-Aug-22 10:36:03.0000 CUT","-30.14589",""
"sensor_1","9-Aug-22 10:36:04.0000 CUT","-29.70199",""
"* End Repeat...","","",""
"*> sensor_2"," 09-aug-22 10:36"," 09-aug-22 10:36"," 100000000000"
"sensor_2","9-Aug-22 10:36:00.5000 CUT","-29.25809",""
"sensor_2","9-Aug-22 10:36:01.5000 CUT","-32.17654",""
"sensor_2","9-Aug-22 10:36:02.5000 CUT","-28.54631",""
"sensor_2","9-Aug-22 10:36:03.5000 CUT","-27.51562",""
"sensor_2","9-Aug-22 10:36:04.5000 CUT","-32.42654",""
"* End Repeat...","","",""
"*> sensor_3"," 09-aug-22 10:36"," 09-aug-22 10:36"," 100000000000"
"sensor_3","9-Aug-22 10:36:00.39900 CUT","-26.35991",""
"sensor_3","9-Aug-22 10:36:01.45001 CUT","-26.35991",""
"sensor_3","9-Aug-22 10:36:02.5448 CUT","-28.20952",""
"sensor_3","9-Aug-22 10:36:03.80101 CUT","-32.17654",""
"sensor_3","9-Aug-22 10:36:04.75401 CUT","-32.17654",""
"* End Repeat...","","",""
```

Ideally I would like to format the data in the DF to be as shown below:

[image: dream_DF]

I manage to import it with regular formatted csv, but this is a tricky one.
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share your first attempts? Python has some options to accomplish this task. Buildit library csv or pandas, for example. Knowing what have you try will help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to first format my raw data, then create a dataframe with the filtered data. For example the following code creates a csv file from your raw data:

```
import csv

f = open('output.csv', 'w')
writer = csv.writer(f)
with open('test.csv', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().rstrip()
    split_data = data.split('"')
    filtered_data = [x for x in split_data if len(x) >= 2]
    for ide, element in enumerate(filtered_data):
        if 'sensor' in element:
            normal_offset = [1, 2]
            double_ts_offset = [2, 3]
            if filtered_data[ide + 1] == filtered_data[ide + 2]:
                offset = double_ts_offset
            else:
                offset = normal_offset
            if '>' in element:
                name = element[2:]
            else:
                name = element
            date = filtered_data[ide + offset[0]]
            value = filtered_data[ide + offset[1]]
            writer.writerow([name, date, value])
```

When finished a .csv file like that will result:

```
sensor_1, 09-aug-22 10:36, 100000000000
sensor_1,9-Aug-22 10:36:00.0000 CUT,-31.10765
sensor_1,9-Aug-22 10:36:01.0000 CUT,-30.58978
sensor_1,9-Aug-22 10:36:02.0000 CUT,-30.14589
sensor_1,9-Aug-22 10:36:03.0000 CUT,-30.14589
sensor_1,9-Aug-22 10:36:04.0000 CUT,-29.70199
sensor_2, 09-aug-22 10:36, 100000000000
sensor_2,9-Aug-22 10:36:00.5000 CUT,-29.25809
sensor_2,9-Aug-22 10:36:01.5000 CUT,-32.17654
sensor_2,9-Aug-22 10:36:02.5000 CUT,-28.54631
sensor_2,9-Aug-22 10:36:03.5000 CUT,-27.51562
sensor_2,9-Aug-22 10:36:04.5000 CUT,-32.42654
sensor_3, 09-aug-22 10:36, 100000000000
sensor_3,9-Aug-22 10:36:00.39900 CUT,-26.35991
sensor_3,9-Aug-22 10:36:01.45001 CUT,-26.35991
sensor_3,9-Aug-22 10:36:02.5448 CUT,-28.20952
sensor_3,9-Aug-22 10:36:03.80101 CUT,-32.17654
sensor_3,9-Aug-22 10:36:04.75401 CUT,-32.17654
```

After u read the csv file with pandas you can format the data as u'd like to in your dataframe. Maybe there is a little more filtering required to remove the 'CUT' in the dates.